# No inbox notification for new answer

Tags: bug, notifications

[This answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/45400) was added to a question of mine a few hours ago. However, there is *no* evidence of it in the universal Stack Exchange inbox. (I wouldn't have seen it if it hadn't been in the flag queue, in fact.)

Seems like a bug to me.

Note that the *comment* posted to that answer *did* show up in my inbox.